# Laravel - Defining has-many-through relationship

Tags: laravel

I'm having a problem while creating a Forum with Laravel 5.7

I want to have these three models: User, Category, Thread and Post. The problem is that i don't how to define one of my Thread model relationships.

This model has a creator:

```
public function creator()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

...it has a series of replies:

```
public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

...and, finally, participants:

```
public function participants()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', '???')
}
```

I should get the thread participants through its replies but it don't know if i should put the post class like this:

```
public function participants()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Post')
}
```

...or if this is an special case with some considerations. Any help?

Comment: so your solution didn't work or what?

Comment: It did not because it is expecting a ``post_id`` at user table which is not my case.

Comment: so you have a pivot table between users and posts tables, right?

Comment: if this is the case, check out this [article](https://medium.com/@DarkGhostHunter/laravel-has-many-through-pivot-elegantly-958dd096db)

Comment: I do not. I have three separated tables with no pivot between any of them. Either way, thanks for that article!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `posts` acts as a pivot table, a `BelongsToMany` relationship is the better choice here:

```php
public function participants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'posts');
}
```

Comment: Even thought it works, i'm getting repeated participants. Is there a way to purge those repeated users?

Comment: Forget it! I figure it out. This piece of code can do the job: ``foreach($threads as $thread) $thread->participants->unique();`` Thanks a lot for your help!